# update a table in mysql if the current value is greater than existing minimum value if not ignore that update

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-2.7, mysql-python

consider a table name testing with following attributes

```
+-------+------------+---------------------------+----------+
| id    | test_case  | file_name                 | coverage |
+-------+------------+---------------------------+----------+
|  8645 | test case1 | /vendor/src/kmod/vendor.c |       32 |
| 12456 | test case4 | /vendor/src/kmod/vendor.c |       28 |
| 20258 | test case3 | /vendor/src/kmod/vendor.c |       30 |
+-------+------------+---------------------------+----------+
```

As in this table when every new insert into table comes it has to check whether new coverage value is greater than min coverage value of existing if that is true ,i need to update new entry with existing min coverage value so that i can keep only top 3 highest coverage value in table.

consider a new entry has came with coverage= 29 as it is greater than min(coverage)=28 then i need to update coverage value with 29 and test case name.

using python-mysql i am doing so please let me know python mysql query/code to do this following above.

I am inserting values to table from a list using python

```
for x,y in zip(out2,out4):

    cur.execute("insert into testing(test_case,file_name,coverage) values('test case8',%s,%s) on duplicate file_name like "%s" update coverage=case when values(coverage) then values(coverage) else coverage end",(x,y,x))
    db.commit()
```

so whenever new value comes it has to check with min(coverage) value .if new value is greater than existing min(coverage) it has to update or else it need to ignore that loop

Comment: You are asking for code completion service. Reading your question I see you know what to do: *"it has to check whether new coverage value is greater than min coverage value of existing if that is true"* and this requirement is not in your code snipped. Just write it and if you found some issues reading values from database post here a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What happens if you don't have any entries in your table (or 1 or 2)?

Comment: I would think about a mysql procedure rather than an insert statement.

Comment: @P.Salmon if we dont have entries then it has to insert as a new row

Comment: @danihp code is: query("update testing set coverage="%s" ,test_case="%s" where file_name like"%s" and coverage=(select min(coverage) from testing where file_name like "%s")"),(x,y,z,z)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is too complex for an insert to deal with. In mysql I would use a procedure but you might want to do this in your front end. Pleas note I'm not sure what you want should certain events occur.

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t( id    int , test_case varchar(20), file_name varchar(30), coverage int);

drop procedure if exists t;
delimiter $$
create procedure t(inid    int , intest_case varchar(20), infile_name varchar(30), incoverage int)
begin
    declare cnt int;
    declare minid int;
    declare minvoverage int;
    declare covexists int;
    set cnt = (select count(*) from t where file_name = infile_name);
    set @mincoverage = (select min(coverage) from t where file_name = infile_name);
    set minid = (select min(id) from t where file_name = infile_name and coverage = @mincoverage);
    if cnt < 3  then
        insert into t values (inid,intest_case,infile_name, incoverage);
    else
      if @mincoverage <> incoverage then #retain existsing detail
        if not exists(select 1 from t where file_name = infile_name and coverage = incoverage) then #retain existing detail
            update t
                set test_case = intest_case, coverage = incoverage
                where file_name = infile_name and
                    id = minid;
        end if;
        end if;
    end if;
end$$
delimiter ;


call t(8645 , 'test case1' , '/vendor/src/kmod/vendor.c' ,       32 );
call t(12456, 'test case2' , '/vendor/src/kmod/vendor.c' ,       28 );
call t(20258, 'test case3' , '/vendor/src/kmod/vendor.c' ,       30 );
call t(30000, 'test case4' , '/vendor/src/kmod/vendor.c' ,       27 );

select * from t;
```

result

```
+-------+------------+---------------------------+----------+
| id    | test_case  | file_name                 | coverage |
+-------+------------+---------------------------+----------+
|  8645 | test case1 | /vendor/src/kmod/vendor.c |       32 |
| 12456 | test case4 | /vendor/src/kmod/vendor.c |       27 |
| 20258 | test case3 | /vendor/src/kmod/vendor.c |       30 |
+-------+------------+---------------------------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: but in result its showing 27 instead of 28 on 2nd row

Comment: If you have a rule which says an update must have a greater value than the min then you need to test for this before the update.

Comment: I'm getting error as ERROR 1241:operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Edited to include test for > min. BTW you might want to include the update tests on the insert.